# Entropy of a mealy machine

Tags: markov-chains, automata, entropy, hidden-markov-models

I have a finite state machine with binary input, and I map each state non-injectively to letters of an output alphabet, here also binary.

Assuming the binary input is uniformly random, how much information is still in the output?

More precisely, if $X_n$ is the random variable that contains the output of the machine at step $n$, what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{H(X_0,\ldots,X_n)}{n}$?

> Simple example:
>
> States: A, B, C, D, E
>   Transitions:
>
> ```
>   | 0 | 1
> A | B | C
> B | B | C
> C | A | E
> D | A | E
> E | A | D
> ```
>
> Outputs:
>
> ```
> A | 1
> B | 0
> C | 0
> D | 1
> E | 0
> ```
>
> Example: (initial state B)
>
> ```
> Input:   011011100100110
> States:  BCEACEDABCABCEA
> Output:  000100110010001
> ```

Comment: It would help me equally to know this for a Moore automaton.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995863800133 might be relevant. After more reading, I get the impression that there is no simple formula which provides this information.

Comment: https://www.math.ubc.ca/~marcus/pubs_electronic/hmm_analyiticty.pdf is a paper from this century, which also does not mention any nice results here.

Comment: It would help to specify the random variables of interest, such as $X$ and $Y$ for quantities like $H(X)$ or $I(X;Y)$.  This also requires a probability model.

Comment: I clarified that the binary input is uniformly random, and what variable’s entropy I look for. Does that help?

Comment: In this case it looks like you can draw the 3-state Markov chain, find hte steady state distribution $\pi_a, \pi_b, \pi_c$, then the steady state distribution for the output $X$ is $P[X=1]=\pi_b$, $P[X=0]=\pi_a+\pi_c$.

Comment: But the steady-state distribution is not the entropy, is it? (I tried this, and the number is too large.)

Comment: $H(X_n) = \sum_{i=0}^1 P[X_n=i]\log_2(1/P[X_n=i])$, which converges to a number as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and you can calculate that number via the steady state probabilities of your Markov chain.  Of course $0 \leq H(X_n)\leq 1$ (since $X_n$ is binary-valued), and so  $H(X_n)/n\rightarrow 0$. Perhaps you really want $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)/n$.

Comment: For this problem you can do these steps: (i) Draw the 3-state Markov chain for $Y_n \in \{a,b,c\}$, (ii) Convince yourself that in this very special case (with binary input being i.i.d. and equally likely 0 or 1), $X_n$ evolves as a 2-state Markov chain and draw that.  So $H(X_n|X_1, ..., X_{n-1}) = H(X_n|X_{n-1})$.  (iii) Since we have a finite state ergodic Markov chain, you can use the formula $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H(X_1,...,X_n)/n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H(X_n|X_{n-1})$.

Comment: Hmm, maybe my simplified example was not well choses. Of course it would be easy if there is an equivalent markov-chain where state and output is the same. (This is what you are suggesting to construct, right?)

Comment: So, can you compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H(X_n|X_{n-1})$ for your example ?

Comment: Not obviously; the output at step $n$ does not directly depends in non-trivial ways on the previous output; the hidden markov state seems to prevent that.

Comment: Well you said "of course it would be easy" but now you are changing that opinion? I think, before you start changing the question to a harder one, you should compute the answer to the easier question.  Anyway, it looks to me like if $X_n=1$ that implies $X_{n+1}=0$.

Comment: Ok, let me put in the (slightly) more complicated machine that I care about, so that I don’t by accident oversimplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my concrete application I later learned that I am really interested in the collision entropy (or Rený entropy), not the usual Shannon entropy.

For that case, I solved this problem by converting the Mealy automaton to a Markov chain (see section 2.2 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1163 for details).

For these I could then calculate the Rený entropy with the method published as http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ISIT44484.2020.9174390 (also available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.09699).